# Overload bracket operators [] to get and set

Tags: c++, indexing, overloading, square-bracket

I have the following class:

```
class risc { // singleton
    protected:
        static unsigned long registers[8];

    public:
        unsigned long operator [](int i)
        {
            return registers[i];
        }
};
```

as you can see I've implemented the square brackets operator for "getting".
Now I would like to implement it for setting, i.e.: `risc[1] = 2`.

How can it be done?

Comment: I came across to this because of this video which I am watching as of now -
https://youtu.be/ux3s1IIvNdg?t=603

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Try this:

```
class risc { // singleton
protected:
    static unsigned long registers[8];

public:
    unsigned long operator [](int i) const    {return registers[i];}
    unsigned long & operator [](int i) {return registers[i];}
};
```

Comment: You can also return a `const long&`. If it weren't a native type then that way would be preferred but for types like `long` it's fine to return it by value.

Comment: Note that it would be a good idea to add a test on i to make sure it's a number between 0 and 7 inclusive. And when dealing with much more complex types than a long, you generally create a reference class (riscDataRef) which holds the necessary information to let you make changes to the main class.

Comment: Shouldn't the ints be replaced with size_t?

Comment: @Andrew 
unsigned long operator [](int i) const    {return registers[i];}
Will the above be called ?
I see the other one being called for both getting and setting
unsigned long & operator [](int i) {return registers[i];}

Comment: @tanweeralam The const variant will be called when the object or reference on which it's called is const.  E.g. `const risc r; r[0];`

Comment: @AndrewDurward
I used your code and called like this
 risc m;
 m[0]=1; 
 DEBUG_PRINT("%d",m[0]);//{I expect the const one to be called here}.



Even though the answer is correct printed, in both cases only the second function is called. unsigned long & operator [](int i) {return registers[i];}

Comment: @tanweeralam I've already addressed this.  See my previous comment.  If that doesn't help then please post a new question rather than using the comments section.

Comment: @AlexisWilke, STL containers have the `at` function for this purpose which checks the boundaries.

Answer (score 18):

You need to return a reference from your `operator[]` so that the user of the class use it for setting the value. So the function signature would be `unsigned long& operator [](int i)`.