# Is there language with such implementation of lists?

Tags: arrays, list, language-design

Is there language in which integer variables are stored in list/array by reference, not by value?
I.e.

```
a = 1
l = [a]
print(l) # [1]
a += 1
print(l) # [2]
```

Comment: It is incorrect expression.

Comment: What is the benefit of the semantics you are suggesting? It seems a bit awkward with special cases (*e.g.*, certain operations only work if the list has one element).

Comment: Which operations? I want to see benefits and drawbacks in this hypothetical language, because can imagine too little on my own.

Comment: [] + [] == []; [] + [1] == [1]; [1, 2] + [1] == [1, 2, 1]. List joining works even for empty lists. I cannot understand your example.

Comment: I misunderstood your original semantic, so I deleted my other comments. That was my fault.

Comment: If you are talking about list joining, then several languages will use `+` to join lists. Python and Ruby, for example, join lists with `+`: `[1] + [2] == [1,2]`, etc. Regarding the reference, I'm not sure what language would use  references for integers in a list. They do use references for more complex data types in a list. So in Ruby, for example, if I say `a = 1`, define `x = [a]`, then `x == [1]`. If I then increment `a` so that `a == 2`, we still have `x == [1]`. But if I say `y = [x]` (so y == [[1]]` then do `x[0] += 1`, then I have `x == [2]` and `y == [[2]]`. That's Ruby specifically.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any language that does this for immediate types like numbers and booleans. Performance gets very bad if numbers are mutable objects. Performance gets very bad for GC VMs if numbers are mutable types on the heap.

I've seen people fake that kind of functionality in OO languages. See this post. [Square bracket [] operator overloading c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42975152/square-bracket-operator-overloading-c)